# Display none will disable the hover effect

Tags: jquery, css, display

I am using this css dropdown menu: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_button

and I am doing a jquery .on("click", event with a ajax call.
After the ajax call (if successful) I am using this jquery code to close the the dropdown:

```
success: function(data){
$(".dropdown-content").css("display", "none"); 
...
```

it works and the dropdown disappears after the click, but other dropdowns loose the hover popup feature and are not shown anymore.
How could I edit the code so it just hide the open dropdown and do NOT deactivate the hover pop up after the hiding effect?

Comment: The drop-down menu is being shown via the CSS :hover attribute.  Adding the css rule "display:none;" will override any css rules since the new css rule is on the object itself.

Comment: @hillcode best way is to make a class as a helper that has display: none and .addClass(), .removeClass(), .toggleClass() based on what you need. setting the css as display none will create problems because it happens inline and overrides any css that's not inline. That being said, you need to show use more code and a verifiable example as per stack overflow's guide.

Comment: Try using "visibility" and "hidden" instead.

Comment: Do you have any examples how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try using $(this).css("display", "none"); instead of $(".dropdown-content").css("display", "none");

Comment: not working. I will try Jabberwockies solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give all your `.dropdown-content` additional ID's? Then listen to what button was clicked and save the ID in a variable. Then use the variable to hide your specific dropdown.

```
var clicked = "";
$('.your-targets').click(function(e) {
   clicked = e.target.id;
});
```

Use `clicked` now to do stuff.

Comment: There are around 2000 dropdowns so giving them a unique id is not a solution at the moment.